# Inspiration to VS inspiration for

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english, british-english

Please check both sentences and let me know what is difference between them.

> He is an **inspiration for** us.

**VS**

> He is an **inspiration to** us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We wouldn't really say that someone is a inspiration for us. A person can "inspire us" or be "an inspiration to us." A person can also be the inspiration for a song, a book, a movie, etc.

### In other words...

> **inspiration for** = an object/idea that helped create another object/idea
>
> **inspiration to** = an object/idea that motivates a person

Answer (score 5):

"inspiration to/or for somebody" =a person or thing that makes you want to be better, more sucessful,etc. So both mean the same thing. Also, we can say:"an inspiration for something" example:"We're searching for some inspiration for a new car design."